# Need 2 radio button but each of them in different Composite group in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I need 2 radio button but each of them in different Composite group in SWT. I would need single selection among them. Please help me with the code. (Need **without** using swing ButtonGroup)

```
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    Default = new Group(shell,SWT.RADIO);
    Default.setText("Default");
    Default.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    compbutton = new Button(Default,SWT.RADIO);
    compbutton.setText("Play against Computer");
    pl2button = new Button(shell,SWT.RADIO);
    pl2button.setText("Player1 Vs Player2");
```

When I try to select radio button, both get selected.I need only one of them to get selected.

Comment: Share the code you tried and we can help you with what needs to be corrected to get the expected result.

Comment: I have added code above, please check and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below approach if you don't want to use `ButtonGroup`

- Add Selection Action Listener (`button.addSelectionListener`) to both the buttons
- In the action listener of first button, clear the second button
- Similarly in the action listener of second button, clear the first button